# The sorting by newest on jobs seems to be broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The start of the list seems to be set on '2 days ago' and if you jump to the last few pages it will then start with items like '21 days ago' or less.

Here is a link to page 92 of 95 sorted by 'newest' showing jobs posted around '22 hours ago': [Demo Link](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab&sort=p&pg=92)

Comment: yup, there's a bug there. fixing it right now

Answer (score 1):

I was doing some performance work in this area and screwed up a cast resulting in the loss of precision of a `double` used by the newest sorting calculation. Fix is going out to prod right now. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Thanks for knocking out that bug so quick!

Answer (score 0):

Still broken!

Jobs > sort by newest. Have recently seen results that are sorted as 2 days, 21 days, 2 weeks, etc.

Pic shows a different sort error.

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGVDw.png)